# Вызов noexcept(false) функции

Tags: c++, visual-c++, исключения, c++17, clion

Есть вот такой код

```cpp
void ThrowDecl() noexcept(false) {}

void Throwing() noexcept(false) {
    throw std::exception();
}

void NoThrow() noexcept {
    ThrowDecl();
    Throwing();
    throw std::runtime_error("Error");
}

int main() {
    NoThrow();
    return 0;
}
```

Сейчас, при компиляции я получаю только один warning на строку `throw std::runtime_error("Error");` тогда как вызов функций, которые потенциально могут выбрасывать исключения из функции, которая эти исключения выбрасывать не может, никак компилятором не отмечаются.

Вопрос: а можно ли все-таки как-то увидеть три warning?

Компилирую при помощи Visual Studio. Но если предупреждения будет показывать IDE (CLion), то меня это тоже устроит.

Comment: Заглянул в последний черновик 20го стандарта [N4868](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4868.pdf), § 14.5, Example 2 (457 страница по внутрикнижной нумерации). Написано, что вызов функции, которая потенциально может выбросить исключение, изнутри функции, помеченной как `noexcept` является валидным. По-видимому, в соответствии со стандартом, предупреждений быть и не должно

Comment: `noexcept` ничего не говорит о том, выбрасываются ли внутри функции исключения или нет. Собственно глобальный анализ кидания исключений видимо и не производится. В данном случае можно пометить `Throwing` как `[[noreturn]]` тогда будет предупреждение о недостижимом коде после.

Comment: @user7860670 `Throwing` может бросать исключение только при определенных условиях, так что `[[noreturn]]` здесь не применим

Answer (score 1):

`noexcept(false)` эквивалентен отсутствию `noexcept` (везде кроме деструкторов, возможно еще чего-то).

То, что для `Throwing();` нет варнинга (тогда как для прямого броска исключения он есть), выглядит как небольшая недоработка компилятора, при условии что компилятор видит тело функции. Отсутствие варнинга для `ThrowDecl();` выглядит логично (как и для всех функций, тела которых компилятор не видит).

Одна из причин использовать `noexcept` - сообщить компилятору что-то, чего он не знает.

Например, вам, как программисту, может быть известно, что какая-то не-`noexcept` функция не может выбросить исключение на конкретных аргументах, или еще по какой-то причине.

Или, возможно, функция никогда не бросает исключений, но `noexcept` на ней забыт, а вы не можете его добавить, потому что функция библиотечная.

Или наоброт, исключение возможно, но вы уверены, что не сможете продолжить нормальную работу после него, поэтому предпочтете сразу получить `std::terminate`.

Comment: Вопрос был не о том, когда использовать `noexcept`, а как получить предупреждение о том, что я забыл в noexcept функцию добавить try-catch()

Comment: @AntonShchyrov *"как получить предупреждение"* Видимо никак. Попробовал собрать MSVC с флагом `/Wall` и клангом с `-Weverything`, и на эти два вызова варнингов не было. Можете написать свою утилиту на основе libclang, которая бы это обнаруживала.